# Error in Xtemplate Parsing

Tags: php

I have the error in parsing the .html page for according to the user type. I cannot assign the page to the user if he is "Individual".

How can i correct it ?

Here is my xtemplate code :

```
<?php


//Fetch Header
require('headers.php');

//Let template know what page we're on
    $req=$_SESSION["usertype"];    
   if($req=="Agent")
{
$xtpl->assign("myaccountagent");
$xtpl->assign_file('currentpage', 'myaccountagent.html');
}

    elseif($req=="Builder"){
$xtpl->assign("myaccountbuilder");
$xtpl->assign_file('currentpage', 'myaccountbuilder.html');  
}
     elseif($req=="Individual"){
$xtpl->assign("myaccountindividual");
$xtpl->assign_file('currentpage', 'myaccountindividual.html');  
}

$xtpl->assign('myfavorites','on');
$xtpl->assign_file('currentmemberpage', 'purchase.html');    
$xtpl->assign_file('currentmemberpage', 'buyos.html');
$xtpl->assign_file('currentmemberpage', 'buyourservice.html');


require('content/storyboxes/purchasestep1.php');
require('content/storyboxes/membersaved.php');        
require('content/storyboxes/propertyresults.php');
require('content/storyboxes/myleadresults.php');*/
require('content/storyboxes/requirementresults.php');  */

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should modify your code as follows :

```
$xtpl->assign("*usertype","on");
```

*usertype denotes the user that you use (Individual or Builder or Agent).

Once you modify the above code for all the users.

The xtemplate will assign the pages according to the User type.